# Django give a Like Button using JS and DOM result ->404

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I got problem with 'live' like unlike button in Django and JavaScript DOM

after button is clicked I got an error

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/24 404 (Not Found)
likePost @ javascripts.js:24
(anonymous) @ javascripts.js:40
javascripts.js:7
```

I don't know if the problem is in the 'await fetch' function or maybe I used the wrong class or id somewhere.
Where to start?

javascript.js

```
const reloadPostHTML = async (postId) => {
  const homePageResponse = await fetch(window.location.href);
  const newHTML = await homePageResponse.text();
  const newDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(newHTML, "text/html");
  console.log(newDocument)
  const newPostElem = newDocument
    .querySelector(`[data-post-id='${postId}']`)
    .closest(".post");
  const oldPostElem = document
    .querySelector(`[data-post-id='${postId}']`)
    .closest(".post");
  oldPostElem.innerHTML = newPostElem.innerHTML;
  makeLikeButton(oldPostElem.querySelector(".like-button-wrapper"));
};

const likePost = async (postId, csrfToken) => {
    await fetch(`/like/${postId}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken
      }
    });
    reloadPostHTML(postId);
  };

const makeLikeButton = (elem) => {
  elem.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const postId = elem.dataset.postId;
    const csrfToken = elem.dataset.csrfToken;
    likePost(postId, csrfToken);
  });
};

const makeLikeButtons = () => {
  for (let elem of document.getElementsByClassName("like-button-wrapper")) {
    makeLikeButton(elem);
  }
};
makeLikeButtons();
```

urls.py

```
    path(
        'article_detail/<int:pk>/',
        login_required(
            ArticleDetail.as_view(template_name = "web/article_detail_view.html")
        ),
        name='article_detail'
        ),
    path('like/<int:pk>', views.like, name='like'),
```

In the views should I also use  "if request.method == "POST":" ?
views.py

```
def like(request, pk):

    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get("article_id"))
    if article.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        article.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        article.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article_detail", args=[int(pk)]))
```

and detail_view.py

class .post is in  thats why i used .closest(".post") in javascript.js

```
<div class="card post"> ........
                <div class="like-button-wrapper"
          data-post-id='{{ article.pk }}'
          data-csrf-token='{{ csrf_token }}'>

    {% if liked %}
    <button class="btn btn-danger position-relative" type="submit" id="like" name="article_id"
        value="{{article.id}}">
        <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down">
        </i>
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary position-relative" type="submit" id="like" name="article_id"
        value="{{article.id}}">
        <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up">
        </i>
        <span
            class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
            {{ likes }}
        </span>
    </button>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: `like/<int:pk>` django adds slash at the end so add slash `like/<int:pk>/` like this or if you don't want to add then set this setting **[`APPEND_SLASH = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#append-slash)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it it was a error 404 came from views.py get_or_404

Now I just rebuild the like function in views and its working as should

```
def like(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get("article_id"))
        article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)

        if article.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            article.likes.remove(request.user)
            liked = False
        else:
            article.likes.add(request.user)
            liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article_detail", args=[int(pk)]))
```

Comment: get_object_or_404 is the right approach you just used wrong value to filter with

Comment: Thanks, 
exactly also works fine
article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=pk)